# Read fixed width text file into datatable row by row - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, text, datatable, fixed-width

I have a large fixed width text file, I want to read it row by row and insert into a datatable, or just read it into a datatable. how can I assign that from which to which position one column will be?

I also have to perform some action like trim the extra space of columns for every record.

I tried this code but it gives me datatable with just 3 columns instead of 15

```
string sourcePath = @"c:\\";
string filename = "file.txt";

DataTable dt;

//Create OleDb connection object
using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;" +
            "Data Source=" + sourcePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;\""))
{
    // Open connection 
    cn.Open();

    // Create OleDb Adapter object 
    using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + filename, cn))
    {
        dt = new DataTable("Records");
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        // Display results
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

Sample Data

Sample    Name.......~Address~City~State~12345                                         Contact Name        123-456-7890          Type           Payment
Sample    Name.......~Address~City~State~12345                                         Contact Name        123-456-7890          Type           Payment
Sample    Name.......~Address City~State~12345                                         Contact Name        123-456-7890          Type           Payment
Sample    Name.......~Address City~State~12345                                         Contact Name        123-456-7890          Type           Payment

There is a lot spaces in between..

Comment: what did you try so far? what is the format / structure of your input file?

Comment: I tried OleDb, and file is fixed width text file

Comment: please post some sample rows of your data file

Comment: If it is fixed width text file, I would prefer reading via StreamReader and extracting the column values using Substring and creating datatable.  You may end up writing a wrapper class for this.  Or did you try this? http://www.filehelpers.net/

Comment: you may try using TextFieldParser if you go for manually splitting data

Comment: No I did not try this

Comment: there is good article on code project along with alternatives at the bottom - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13870/Wrapper-Class-for-Parsing-Fixed-Width-Multiple-Sec

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read your text file using OleDb Text Driver you need to provide a [Schema.ini](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx) file that describe the structure of one of the "records" (a line) of your text file

So supposing that your text file contains records in this format:

```
XXXXXYYYYYKKKKKZZZZ
```

(Four fields, each of 5 char) you need to add in the same folder where is located your text file a Schema.ini file with this structure

```
[file.txt]
Format=FixedLength
Col1=CustomerNumber Text Width 5
Col2=CustomerName Text Width 5
Col3=CustomerCity Text Width 5
Col4=CustomerZIP Text Width 5
```

You could find more detail at the MSDN page linked above

Without using OleDb you need to use something already available in the NET Framework, or write your own splitting code, or use a thirdy party library

For your own code approach I would start defining a class for your record.
For example an Customer class could be

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Address {get;set;}
    ... other fields omitted ....
}
```

then you define a `List<Customer>` and start reading your file with

```
List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(filename)
{
    Customer c = new Customer();
    c.Name = line.Substring(0, 10).Trim();
    c.Address = line.Substring(10, 15).Trim();
    ... and so on for all the other fields....

    customers.Add(c);        
}
```

At the end of the loop you have your list filled with your data. Of course if you just need to write everything in another table on a database server you could write the code that inserts/updates the database table directly inside the loop and avoid the loading of the list.

Comment: I don't want to hard code my file name, it is dynamic

Comment: You have two options then. Create the Schema.ini on the fly or create code that read your text file and splits each line according to your substrings.

Comment: I am exploring filehelper for this purpose

Comment: Well good to know how to use it, anyway you need to tell it how to split your lines.